# Why is this R function not replacing a specific value in a given data set?

Tags: r

I'm using [this dataset](https://github.com/hadley/fueleconomy) and am trying to replace a very specific NA value in its `trans` column. Since the value is unknown, my best attempt at fixing the value without removing the whole row is to subsitute it with the most common `trans` value among rows that share other important attributes. No errors are being generated but the NA value is not being replaced. What am I missing?

```
library(fueleconomy)
library(data.table)

get(data("vehicles", package = "fueleconomy"))

sub_na_trans <- function(match) {
  vehicles[match & is.na(vehicles$trans), ] <- data.frame(replace_na(
    vehicles[match & is.na(vehicles$trans), ],
    list(trans = setDT(vehicles[match, ])[, N:=.N, trans][N==max(N)][, N:=NULL]$trans[1])))
}

sub_na_trans(vehicles$make == 'Ford' &
              vehicles$model == 'F150 Pickup 2WD' &
              vehicles$year == 1984 &
              vehicles$class == 'Standard Pickup Trucks 2WD')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK.

Change <- to <<- within your function.

```
vehicles[match & is.na(vehicles$trans), ] <- 

vehicles[match & is.na(vehicles$trans), ] <<-
```

We can refer global variable's value from inside a function.

But we cannot change it with <- there in R.

For such purpose, we can use <<- instead.

.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/40650820/11634537

[How do you use "<<-" (scoping assignment) in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2628621/11634537)